# What is this java feature about specifying a type in the middle of a call?

Tags: java, types, casting

Since I don't really know how to describe this, it will be difficult but I'll try.

For the context, I'm working with 2 classes

- Person
- Customer extends Person

I got an array of `Customer` that I received, and I want to put it inside a `Vector<Person>`. When I wrote this code, AndroidStudio autocompleted it like this:

```
Vector<Person> persons = Arrays.<Person>asList(customers)
```

My question is: What is this `<Person>` doing between `Arrays.` and `asList`, since removing it doesn't change anything as Java already infer the type from `Customer` to `Person`.

It seems to me it indicates the type of the List returned by `asList`, but I still don't really understand it's usefulness.

Can someone explain what is it, what it's called and is it's real purpose?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you specifically asking about that syntax, or why it's being used here despite the compilers ability to infer? Do you know about generic types?

Comment: it's Generic Types and is a topic in Java, simply the point is that when you describe **persons** as **Vector<Person>** , for further usage, you do not need to cast  **persons** items to **Person** class to use its method or attributes (if you can!) and compiler assumes **persons** member as objects of **Person** class. And of course it's OK to define it as customer too : **Vector<Customer> persons = Arrays.<Customer>asList(customers)**. Let me know if the explanation is clear please.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I know about generic types ('been in Java for 5 years), and I ask both ^^ I never saw this syntax before, and don't understand why it was being used despite the face that it seems "useless"

Comment: @QuentinBeuvelet The person who wrote this (/ the AndroidStudio autocomplete template that generated this) could have been preferring explicitness over implicitness and inference.

Answer (score 1):

It works for type refering. 
If you call like below.

```
Arrays.<Person>asList(customers)
```

The compiler replace T to Person class

```
// definition
static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)  
// changed
static <Person> List<Person> asList(Person... a)
```